# Deploying node.js web app along with docker

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, docker, npm, npm-install

WE have a  node.js web app.We have deployed it on server with docker.
Its working fine with node version 0.10.25. But right now i have decided it to run on latest version of node 6.5.0

To accomplish this i modified the docker file which is now looking like below

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN echo 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN sudo apt-get install  linux-libc-dev  curl  git-core krb5-multidev libkrb5-dev -y
RUN sudo curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN sudo apt-get install  nodejs -y
RUN sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "node -v"]
RUN sudo npm cache clean
RUN sudo npm install -g bower -y
RUN sudo npm install -g gulp -y
#RUN sudo npm install -g node-sass
#RUN sudo npm install -g eslint -y
#RUN sudo npm install -g htmllint -y
RUN cd /root; git clone -b masterclone  https://consultancy:Admin23@github.com/newapp/web.git
RUN cd /root/web; sudo npm install; sudo bower install --allow-root; gulp clean-build-app-prod
EXPOSE 8000
CMD cd /root/web; NODE_ENV=production node server.js
```

Everything went  fine except the below  line which i guess causing the problem

```
   "The command '/bin/sh -c cd /root/web; sudo npm install; sudo bower install --allow-root; gulp clean-build-app-prod' returned a non-zero code: 1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the official node image. Here a example file.

```
FROM node:6.5

# Enviroment variables
ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL warn
ENV USER node
ENV HOMEDIR /data

# add user node and change dir working dir
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash ${USER}
RUN mkdir -p ${HOMEDIR}
WORKDIR ${HOMEDIR}

# install all dependencies
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install --production

# add node content
COPY . .

USER node
EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably simpler to base your file off of the [official NodeJS image](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/). For v6.5, that means that `FROM ubuntu:14.04` becomes `FROM node:6.5`.

Also, instead of doing `RUN cd /root/web` over and over, you might want to change the working directory with `WORKDIR /root/web`.